# What is the relationship between the minimal polynomial of $T$ and the minimal polynomials of the component maps?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb R$, and let 
$T_1 :V\rightarrow V$ and $T_2:W\rightarrow W$ be two linear transformations whose minimal polynomials are given respectively by
 $f(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1$ and $g(x)=x^4-x^2-2$.

Let $T :V\oplus W\rightarrow V\oplus W$ be the linear transformation defined by 
$T(v,w)=(T_1(v) ,T_2(w))$ for $(v,w) \in V\oplus W$, and let $h(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$.

What is the degree of $h(x)$, and what is the nullity of $T$ (dimension of the nullspace of $T$) ?

Comment: Why do you hesitate to call this particular minimal polynomial a polynomial?

Comment: I know how to writte a  polynomial in a single indeterminate. Shall I proceed here like in "normal" polynomials? deg(h(x)) = 4?

Comment: The degree of a polynomial is a number and Null$(T)$ is a vector space. Neither is a polynomial. What you are asking is not clear to me.

Comment: h(x) = (f(x), g(x)) is still a polynomial?

Comment: What do you mean by $(f(x), g(x))$? That is a pair of polynomials.

Comment: Since $T$ is a linear map on a finite dimensional vector space, it will have a minimal polynomial.   Perhaps your Question is more clearly stated as, what is the relationship between the minimal polynomial of $T$ and the minimal polynomials of the component maps, i.e with $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: hardmath, tks, perfect

Comment: I made a few more edits, including replacing $+$ by $\oplus$ to indicate an external direct sum.  Please add to the Question your own thoughts about how to approach this problem.  I will then vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T :V\oplus W\rightarrow V\oplus W$ be the linear transformation defined by 
$T(v,w)=(T_1(v) ,T_2(w))$ for $(v,w) \in V\oplus W$, and let $h(x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$.

So minimal polynomial $h(x)$ of $T$ is the $lcm(g(x), f(x))$.
Given $f(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1$ and $g(x)=x^4-x^2-2$.

After computing the lcm you'll find $h(x)=x^5+x^4-x^3-x^2-2x-2$. Hence $deg(h(x))=5$. Also notice that then constant term of $h(x)$ is not zero, which represents the value of the determinant, hence $nullity(T)=0$

**Note:**

The minimal polynomial of $T$ is the l.c.m of minimal polynomials of $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Comment: Also nullity of $T$ is (in general) the nullity of $T_1$ plus the nullity of $T_2$.  It would not be hard to throw in a proof of the claim, that the minimal polynomial of $T$ is the least common multiple of the minimal polynomials of $T_1$ and of $T_2$.

Comment: Welcome downvoter, please take some pain and explain your reason.